# Where is this building?

Tags: russia, where-on-earth, identify-this, architecture

It's possible it's in St Petersbourg but I do not know and I do not have a higher resolution picture. Question originally from http://www.gyakorikerdesek.hu/utazas__egyeb-kerdesek__7933933-felismeri-valaki-ezt-az-epuletet-mi-a-neve-es-hol-van .

[image: Mysterious Building]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a building [near Zvyozdnaya metro station](https://www.google.cz/maps/@59.8335821,30.3486858,3a,75y,127.22h,95.28t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1snQ4WTZG9QjJXBU4wE8DeNg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1?hl=en) in St. Petersburg:

[image]

Exact GPS location: [59.833285, 30.349010](https://goo.gl/maps/VhpyUkrvRmM2). The letters on top say "Beer House", which is a [local chain of pubs](http://beerhousebar.ru/).

Comment: Wow! I was trying to read those letters as Cyrillic.